# $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)=\mathbb{Z}$ possible?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory, riemann-surfaces, covering-spaces

Is it possible to have $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)=\mathbb{Z}$?

My question comes from the link beetween covering and field extensions. For covering the simplest example is $\operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{S}^1)=\mathbb{Z}$.

Maybe something like $\mathscr{M}(\mathbb{C})/\mathscr{M}(\mathbb{C}^*)$ where $\mathscr{M}(X)$ is the field of meromorphics functions on a Riemann surface?

Comment: To reconcile the similarities between fundamental groups and Galois groups you need to pass to the profinite completion of the fundamental group.  The two theories are unified in etale cohomology.

Comment: The whole point of using algebraic fundamental group is that : the galois correspondence between coverings spaces and galois groups isn't good enough for one to have a concrete dictionary between them, as fundamental group of a space might not be profinite, whereas every galois group is.

Comment: ah, @jkramerm47, you beat me by seconds.

Comment: @jkramerm47 So there should be a example in etale cohomology?

Comment: @Soranzo Example of what?

Comment: @jkramerm47 Ok, it seems I don't understand the term "unified" correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Not the same but related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871485/is-there-a-field-extension-k-bbb-q-such-that-textaut-bbb-qk-cong?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pretty close: there are fields whose absolute Galois groups are the [profinite integers](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Profinite_completion_of_the_integers) $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$. In particular every finite field has this property. The finite extensions of finite fields look exactly like the finite covers of $S^1$ (but the infinite extensions are more complicated).

Comment: All is clear. What a same!

Answer (score 10):

No: every Galois group is profinite, and any infinite profinite group has cardinality at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.